# Nslog data in text?

Tags: objective-c

How can i put the data from NSlogs in things like:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"I just scored xx 'touches'"];
```

NSlog;

```
NSLog(@"Game over score: %i",counter);
```

output;

```
2012-01-06 04:27:00.296 [317:707] Game over score: **31**
```

The **31** i want on the xx in first code line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSString`'s `-stringWithFormat:` method:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just scored %d 'touches'", counter]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:"I just scored %d 'touches'", counter]];
```